# No debugging symbol found in debugging with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, gdb

I am debugging C4.5 code with gdb and I got the error as

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./consult...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

C4.5's  make file has -g in CFLAG and the whole file is attached. I followed some discussions for similar discussions. But still have problem.

```
Makefile
CFLAGS = -g -O2    
core.ln = \
    getnames.ln getdata.ln trees.ln getopt.ln header.ln    
trees.ln = \
    besttree.ln build.ln info.ln discr.ln contin.ln subset.ln\
    prune.ln stats.ln st-thresh.ln classify.ln confmat.ln\
    sort.ln $(core.ln)    
rules.ln = \
    rules.ln genlogs.ln genrules.ln makerules.ln prunerule.ln\
    siftrules.ln testrules.ln stats.ln confmat.ln sort.ln $(core.ln)    
core = \
    getnames.o getdata.o trees.o getopt.o header.o    
trees = \
    besttree.o build.o info.o discr.o contin.o subset.o prune.o\
    stats.o st-thresh.o classify.o confmat.o sort.o $(core)    
rules = \
    rules.o genlogs.o genrules.o makerules.o prunerule.o\
    siftrules.o testrules.o stats.o confmat.o sort.o $(core)    
c4.5:   c4.5.o $(trees)
cc -o c4.5 c4.5.o $(trees) -lm   
c4.5gt:
    cat defns.i types.i\
        c4.5.c\
        besttree.c build.c info.c discr.c contin.c subset.c\
        prune.c stats.c st-thresh.c confmat.c sort.c\
        getnames.c getdata.c classify.c trees.c header.c\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|types.i|extern.i|buildex.i' >c4.5gt.c
    cc -O4 -o c4.5gt c4.5gt.c -lm
    rm c4.5gt.c  
c4.5rules: c4.5rules.o $(rules)
    cc -o c4.5rules c4.5rules.o $(rules) -lm  

c4.5rulesgt:
    cat defns.i types.i\
        c4.5rules.c\
        rules.c genlogs.c genrules.c makerules.c prunerule.c\
        siftrules.c testrules.c stats.c confmat.c sort.c\
        getnames.c getdata.c classify.c trees.c header.c\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|types.i|extern.i|rulex.i' >c4.5rulesgt.c
    cc -O4 -o c4.5rulesgt c4.5rulesgt.c -lm
    rm c4.5rulesgt.c    
consult: consult.o userint.o $(core)
    cc -o consult consult.o userint.o $(core)    
consultr: consultr.o rules.o userint.o $(core)

    cc -o consultr consultr.o rules.o userint.o $(core)


.c.o:
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c $<


all:
    make c4.5
    make c4.5rules
    make consult
    make consultr
    cc -o xval-prep xval-prep.c
    cc -o average average.c -lm


$(trees): defns.i types.i extern.i
$(rules): defns.i types.i extern.i
```

When I check file consult for stripped / or not stripped, it is not stripped.
What else I still need to add into the make file so that I can debug consult api with gdb?
Thanks

Comment: Turn of optimization. Change `-O2` to `-O0`

Comment: Please remove temporary files, re-run `make` and attach its output to the question. Your makefile don't have `clean`-like target, you probably have built this without `-g` first, then added it and tried to re-make; it wouldn't rebuild anything.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
cc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11  -Wshadow ab.c -o ab


taras@taras: $ gdb ./ab

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
...

Reading symbols from ./ab...done.

Starting program: /home/taras/ab 7

(gdb) b 7

Breakpoint 1 at 0x40052e: file ab.c, line 7.

(gdb) r

Starting program: /home/taras/ab 7

Breakpoint 1, main () at ab.c:7

7               int n = 0, m = 0;

(gdb) n
```